# How to convert a jsonObject into a .json file for an email attachment?

Tags: java

If I've got the following JsonObject set up:

```
JsonElement testBatchJsonElement = MqGsonFactory.getGson().toJsonTree(testBatch);
JsonObject testBatchJsonObject = testBatchJsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
```

And the final jsonObject is represented like this:

```
{
   "batchDuration":"7s 984ms",
   "batchParameters":{},
   "executionErrors":[],
   "friendlyBatchEndTime":"10/19/2017 12:44:16 PM",
   "friendlyBatchStartTime":"10/19/2017 12:44:08 PM",
   "id":"026e3b2074e246008ace99dbd6d93640"
}
```

How would I go about converting this `testBatchJsonObject` to a **.json** file to be added to an email as an attachment that I've set up here:

```
public void sendNotification(String from, String pass, String host, int port, String[] to, String subject, String body) throws EmailException {
    log.trace("Beginning sendNotification function");
    Email gmail = new SimpleEmail();
    gmail.setSmtpPort(port);
    gmail.setHostName(host);
    gmail.setAuthentication(from, pass);
    gmail.setSSLOnConnect(true);
    gmail.setFrom(from);
    gmail.setSubject(subject);
    gmail.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    gmail.addTo(to);
    gmail.send();
}
```

Comment: There's no need for a file. You can use [`JsonElement#toString()`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#toString--) to convert `testBatchJsonElement` to a `String` and pass it to the method as `String body`.

Comment: Izruo, I'm actually needing the external file so that I can use it as an attachment in an email.

Comment: In that case you have to write it to a file. For a convenient way to have it deleted afterwards you may have a look on the [`Files.createTempFile(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) methods.